# C++ Code does not accumulate sum in variable during for loop and provides only final iteration value

Tags: c++

My problem is that the variable 'scoreA' should be the accumulation of all the values generated during each iteration of the for loop. However, I am not getting the accumulated value and get only the value at the final iteration. Could someone Kindly help me out as I am new to C++. I have defined scoreA outside the for loop so my understanding is that the value of scoreA should be the accumulated value for all the iterations. But my guess is that it is being reassigned to 0 because of which it is unable to accumulate the value.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

  map<string,int> Score_Scheme;
  string StringA = "aaaa";

int Score_Compute(string StringA);
int Base_case_A(int lenA);

int main ()
{
  Score_Scheme["ac"] = -1;
  Score_Scheme["ag"] = -2;
  Score_Scheme["at"] = -1;
  Score_Scheme["a-"] = -3;
  Score_Scheme["cg"] = -3;
  Score_Scheme["ct"] = -2;
  Score_Scheme["c-"] = -4;
  Score_Scheme["gt"] = -2;
  Score_Scheme["g-"] = -2;
  Score_Scheme["t-"] = -1;
  Score_Scheme["--"] = 0;
  Score_Scheme["aa"] = 5;
  Score_Scheme["cc"] = 5;
  Score_Scheme["gg"] = 5;
  Score_Scheme["tt"] = 5;
  Score_Scheme["ca"] = -1;
  Score_Scheme["ga"] = -2;
  Score_Scheme["ta"] = -1;
  Score_Scheme["-a"] = -3;
  Score_Scheme["gc"] = -3;
  Score_Scheme["tc"] = -2;
  Score_Scheme["-c"] = -4;
  Score_Scheme["tg"] = -2;
  Score_Scheme["-g"] = -2;
  Score_Scheme["-t"] = -1;


  int len_StringA = StringA.size ();
  cout<<"length of A is:"<<len_StringA<<"\n";

  Base_case_A(len_StringA);

  return 0;
}

int Base_case_A(int lenA)
{
    int scoreA  = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<lenA;i++)
        {   
            char x[2];
            x[0] = StringA[i];
            x[1] = '-';
            scoreA=scoreA+Score_Compute(x);
            cout<<i<<":"<<scoreA<<"\n";
        }
    cout<<scoreA<<"\n";
    return 0;
}

int Score_Compute(string stringA)
{
    return Score_Scheme[stringA];
}
```

Comment: This won't compile, so what it does is moot.

Comment: The only thing that doesn't compile is there are 2 `main()` functions.  Remove the second one, then [the code compiles](https://ideone.com/2wVOEe), it just doesn't function correctly due to a logic bug in the loop.

Comment: @Remy how about `Base_case_A` in `main`?

Comment: @NeilButterworth that is the erroneous `main()` that needs to be removed. The other `main()` is the correct one to keep.  I've edited the question to remove it now

Comment: @Remy Which one is "the erroneous main"?

Comment: @NeilButterworth the one that doesn't belong in this code, the one I've already removed.  The other `main()` initializes the `std::map` and triggers the loop, so it is obviously the correct one that belongs.

Comment: @Remy I love it when people assume things here rather than asking the OP what they mean.

Comment: @NeilButterworth It really wasn't hard to figure out which one the OP meant to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Score_Compute()` takes a `std::string` as input, but when the loop calls `Score_Compute(x)`, `x` is a `char[2]` containing 2 `char` values neither of which are a null terminator.

When a `char[]` is passed as-is to a `std::string`, the `char[]` decays to `char*`, which `std::string` then assumes to be null-terminated, which yours is not.

So, the `std::string` that `Score_Compute()` receives will be wrong, usually containing *random data* after the characters you did specify (assuming the code doesn't just crash altogether while searching for a null terminator that doesn't exist), and so it will not match any entries in your `std::map`, causing `Score_Compute()` to return 0.

To fix the logic, you need to change the declaration of `x` to `char x[3];` and then add `x[2] = '\0';` before converting to `std::string`:

```
char x[3]; // <-- fix this!
x[0] = StringA[i];
x[1] = '-';
x[2] = '\0'; // <-- add this!
```

Otherwise, you have to specify the correct length when converting to `std::string`:

```
Score_Compute(string(x, 2));
```

Alternatively, simply change `x` to be a `std::string` to begin with:

```
string x(2, '\0');
x[0] = StringA[i];
x[1] = '-';
```

Or:

```
string x;
s.resize(2);
x[0] = StringA[i];
x[1] = '-';
```

Or:

```
string x = " -";
x[0] = StringA[i];
```